# Where should I create UAT branch from - master or dev?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I've got a master branch which represents what's there on production server. I've a dev branch (child of master) which contains work done in the sprint just finished. `master` branch also contains fixes done on production server after getting diverged from dev.

Now I need to merge both of them and create a new branch called `UAT` where it will be tested for production readiness.

So should I?

merge master > dev
   branch uat from dev
   merge uat > master (once uat is stable)

or

branch uat from master
merge dev >  uat
merge uat > master (once uat is stable)

In both cases, developers will carry on working on dev branch.

Comment: Um how did you get into a situation where fixes on production server aren't in dev? Correct that, UAT is a stable dev build and once it's passed muster it can go pre-prod and then prod.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In git, there is no "one way" of managing the code workflow, and you should use what suites your inner workflow best.

On [atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows) web, there are several workflow types compared. In the section "Hotfix branches" of page "Gitflow workflow" (that seems to be best for you) is shown, that you should merge the hotfixes right away into master and develop branches. It is based on workflow defined by [Vincent Driessen at nvie](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

[image: Gitflow workflow]

Then it is obvious the release (or in your case UAT) branch should come from develop branch

Comment: Can I then safely merge `uat` > `master` i.e. merge directly to grand parent branch skipping the merge to parent? Or is it safe to do that?

Comment: as long as your changes to master (ie hotfixes) where incorporated into develop branch too, I think yes, you shoud be safe in merging UAT to master... so the master will become something like "storage for stable releases" and there should not be any other changes except from hotfixes and UAT merges